# Django page no found

Tags: python, django, web

views.py

```
def search_author(request):
   if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
    q = request.GET['q']
    authors =User.objects.filter(username=q)
    return render_to_response('search_results.html',
        {'authors': author, 'query': q})
   else:
    return HttpResponse('Please submit a search term.')
def search_form(request):
    return render_to_response('search_form.html')
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^search_author$',app.views.search_author),
url(r'^search_form$', app.views.search_form)
```

search_form.html

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}
{% block content %}

<form action="/search_author/" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="q">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

search_results.html

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}
{% block content %}


<p>You searched for: <strong>{{ query }}</strong></p>

{% if authors%}
   <p>Found {{ authors|length }} author{{ authors|pluralize }}.</p>
   <ul>
      {% for author in authors %}
      <li>{{ author.username }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
   </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No authors matched your search criteria.</p>
{% endif %}
```

loginparitial.html

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<form id="logoutForm" action="/logout" method="post" class="navbar-right">
{% csrf_token %}
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><span class="navbar-brand">您好 {{ user.username }}!</span></li>
    <li><a href="search_form">查询作者</a></li>
    <li><a href="upload_book"> 发布旧书</a></li>
    <li><a href="user_book_detail" >查看我的书籍</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">    登出</a></li>
</ul>
```

when l click the '查询作者'  in the home page,the error says
    Page not found (404)
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/search_form/

Can anyone help me with my problem ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Where you save your templates?

Comment: app/templates/app

Comment: In settings.py file , which route you set for templates dir. I mean You set like this 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')].

Comment: this one ?   'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates )]

Comment: I have post the answer below, try it

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your regex pattern.

`/search_form/` is different from your specified `^search_form$`. That maps to `/search_form` (No trailing slash). To make it `/search_form/`, just use `^search_form/$`.

Comment: Updated. See the new changes.

Comment: yeah,i tried it,but orrurs a new error says TemplateDoesNotExist at /search_form/
search_form.html

Comment: TemplateDoesNotExist  at /search_form/

Comment: It's because Django cannot find your template. Are you sure you configured the templates directory in your settings file?

Comment: See @neelima 's post

Answer (score 1):

I think you giving wrong routing to templates.

In settings.py you giving templates directory route like this

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

then your templates loaded from main app folder --> templates folder.
You can call templates directly in views.

If you save your templates in another folder in templates folder,then you need to give the template route upto that folder.

For example:
  you saved your templates in main app folder -->templates --> app folder.
then you have to give the route upto to app folder.

like this:

```
def search_form(request):
   return render_to_response('app/search_form.html').
```

Try once..!